# Forcing a reduce phase or a second map reduce job in hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I am running a hive query of the following form:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY ...
SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(...) */ * FROM ...
```

Because of the `MAPJOIN`, the result does not require a reduce phase. The map phase uses about 5000 mappers, and it ends up taking about **50 minutes** to complete the job. It turns out that most of this time is spent copying those 5000 files to the local directory.

To try to optimize this, I replaced `SELECT * ...` with `SELECT DISTINCT * ...` (I know in advance that my results are already distinct, so this doesn't actually change my result), in order to force a second map reduce job. The first map reduce job is the same as before, with 5000 mappers and 0 reducers. The second map reduce job now has 5000 mappers and 3 reducers. With this change, there are now only 3 files to be copied, rather than 5000, and the query now only takes a total of about **20 minutes**.

Since I don't actually need the `DISTINCT`, I'd like to know whether my query can be optimized in a less kludge-y way, without using `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 1):

What about wrapping you query with another SELECT, and maybe a useless WHERE clause to make sure it kicks off a job.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY ...
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(...) */ *
    FROM ..
) x
WHERE 1 = 1
```

I'll run this when I get a chance tomorrow and delete this part of the answer if it doesn't work. If you get to it before me then great.

Another option would be to take advantage of the [virtual columns](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns) for file name and line number to force distinct results. This complicates the query and introduces two meaningless columns, but has the advantage that you no longer have to know in advance that your results will be distinct. If you can't abide the useless columns, wrap it in another SELECT to remove them.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY ...
SELECT {{enumerate every column except the virutal columns}}
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT /*+ MAPJOIN(...) */ *, INPUT__FILE__NAME, BLOCK__OFFSET__INSIDE__FILE 
    FROM ..
) x
```

Both solutions are more kludge-y than what you came up with, but have the advantage that you are not limited to queries with distinct results.

We get another option if you aren't limited to Hive. You could get rid of the `LOCAL` and write the results to HDFS, which should be fast even with 5000 mappers. Then use `hadoop fs -getmerge /result/dir/on/hdfs/` to pull the results into the local filesystem. This unfortunately reaches out of Hive, but maybe setting up a two step Oozie workflow is acceptable for your use case.